# Harry Potter fanfic with Harry attempting suicide using a "slicing curse" taught to him by Dumbledore

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I'm looking for a story, a fanfiction. Here's everything I remember:

1. Dumbledore taught Harry a slicing curse to cut pancakes
2. He used that curse to slit his wrist but cannot manage the other before passing out (Dittany and Fawkes's tears are used to close it mostly)
3. Severus offered him tea when they started to talk
4. Harry started hallucinating when he missed his medications' dose time due to said talk, and Severus calms him down and gets him to relax in a cot in Grimmauld Place
5. Harry has to wear a sling (Remus helps him dress, and uses a sticking charm to his dressing robe) and use a cane
6. Orbs are on his bed so he can get help
7. A tiny bedpost snake holds up his dressing robe and freaks Ron out
8. Diggle hurts Harry's already damaged shoulder and leg
9. Remus (like a boss) punches open a bathroom door
10. Everyone in the Order knows he tried to die and immediately debates on the severity and appropriation of staying on as his guard if "he runs headlong into the enemy"
11. A boggart terrified the hell out of Dumbledore as a dead Harry before Remus calms him down

I've searched for every variation of phrases I could think of.

Comment: *For Thine Is the Power*, most likely.

Comment: It's a good fanfiction. Harry is a Seer, a Metamorphmagus, and also Snape's son. And Voldemort's. And Sirius's. There's a fertility potion involved somewhere.

Comment: Sounds like Dumbledore ran out of important horcruxy things to teach :'D

Answer (score 6):

### *[For Thine Is The Power](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/3800746/1/For-Thine-Is-The-Power)*

All the elements seem to match. Here are the first six.

1. **Dumbledore taught Harry a slicing curse to cut pancakes.**

   > Albus closed his eyes. "I taught him the Slicing Curse," he admitted in a tight 
   >   voice.
   >
   > That got both Remus's and Poppy's attention; both turned to stare at
   >   him. "Albus, what were you thinking?" the witch asked him
   >   incredulously.
   >
   > "I used it on his pancakes," Albus explained distantly. "He asked him
   >   to teach it to him. I did not expect... well."
2. **He used that curse to slit his wrist.**

   > Picking it up, he ran his fingers down its long length, stroking the
   >   wood with water-softened fingers. There was a thought in the back of
   >   his mind, trying to come forwards; rather than chase it, he let his
   >   mind drift, toying absently with eleven inches of holly and phoenix
   >   feather. He remembered, as if in a dream, the day he had bought the
   >   wand, the first spell he had cast with it...
   >
   > ...the spell he had learned that day. The Slicing Curse.
   >
   > Turning over his left hand, he traced the vein along the forearm with
   >   the wand---then he spoke the incantation and did it again.
3. **Severus offered him tea when they started to talk.**

   > Watching the boy out of the corner of his eye, Severus took one of his
   >   own. Absently chewing on it, he waved his wand over the table; a tea
   >   set materialized a moment later. "I fear that long exposure to the
   >   Headmaster has accustomed me to tea with my biscuits," he said wryly.
   >   "If I help you to sit up, do you promise not to move except to drink
   >   your tea?"
   >
   > Potter nodded after a moment. "Please," he said.
4. **Harry started hallucinating when he missed his medications' dose time.**

   > This is getting us nowhere rapidly. They were caught in a catch-22:
   >   the boy's current state was most likely due to lack of this very
   >   potion, for it had some odd withdrawal effects, but the boy's current
   >   state was effectively preventing him from administering it. He could
   >   stupefy the boy and pour the potion down his throat, but he was oddly
   >   reluctant to do so to a child who was so clearly terrified.
5. **Harry has to wear a sling (Remus helps him dress, and uses a sticking charm to his dressing robe) and use a cane.**

   > It took several discreet shortening and widening spells, but finally
   >   Harry was dressed in trousers that would neither catch on the bandages
   >   on his knee, nor trip him up. The short-sleeved shirt was easier--it
   >   only required a bit of widening to the right shoulder to go on
   >   comfortably, and Harry could even get it on by himself. They didn't
   >   bother altering the jacket, which Harry thought was a little new to be
   >   something Charlie no longer wore. Instead, they tucked Harry's arm
   >   into a sling and simply used a weak sticking charm to hold the right
   >   shoulder on. Finally, Madame Pomfrey tied his trainers for him.
6. **Orbs are on his bed so he can get help**.

   > He touched the yellow glass half-orb three times in rapid succession
   >   and they could hear an alarm faintly through the walls. After letting
   >   it sound for a few seconds, he touched it again and it went silent.
   >   "There's two more we've added instead to the headboard above you."

The eleventh bears mentioning as well.

11. **A boggart terrified Dumbledore.**

    > His choked gasp brought Albus running; he stepped aside to allow the
    >   Headmaster to see, whereupon there was a muffled crack and suddenly
    >   Harry was lying in a slowly-spreading pool of his own blood. Remus
    >   drew a shaky breath and closed the closet door firmly, nearly in
    >   Albus's face, before collapsing against it. "Just a boggart," he said
    >   unsteadily. "It was only a boggart."